# vhdl: too many actuals for block...with only 0 formals

Tags: vhdl

Last day, last 3 hours before we give the project and we just realized we have this error!
I am not very good in vhdl so I can't understand what the problem is!

Error (10588): VHDL Generic Map Aspect error at addsub16.vhd(31): too many actuals for block "fulladder16" with only 0 formals

```
LIBRARY ieee;   
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;   

ENTITY addsub16 IS    
 PORT(X, Y    :IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);    
     Add_Sub  :IN STD_LOGIC;    
     Result   :OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);    
     Cout     :OUT STD_LOGIC;   
     Overflow :OUT STD_LOGIC);   
END addsub16;   

ARCHITECTURE Structure OF addsub16 IS    
    COMPONENT fulladder16   
        PORT(Cin      :IN STD_LOGIC;    
             X, Y     :IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);    
             Sum      :OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);     
             Cout     :OUT STD_LOGIC;    
             Overflow :OUT STD_LOGIC);    
    END COMPONENT;    
    SIGNAL y_mod :STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);    
    BEGIN

    gen_XOR:    
    FOR i IN 0 TO 15 GENERATE    
        y_mod(i) <= Y(i) XOR Add_Sub;     
    END GENERATE;     

    adder:fulladder16 GENERIC MAP(16)     
                 PORT MAP(Add_Sub, X, y_mod, Result, Cout, Overflow);    
  END Structure;
```

Comment: You can replace your generate block `gen_XOR` by a single line, which might be more readable: `y_mod <= Y xor (Y'range => Add_Sub);` This expands the single bit `Add_Sub` to as many bits as `Y` has and xors this bits with `Y` to `y_mod` :) -- And of cause, as fruitbat mentioned, you are assigning a generic value to a module which has no generics. Or, you added a generic to your module fulladder16, but forgot to update the component declaration in addsub16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the line:

```
adder:fulladder16 GENERIC MAP(16)
```

The "formal" is a port, generic, etc. declared in the prototype for a component (or whatever). The "actual" is what's mapped to it.

You are mapping 1 actual value to a component (`fulladder16`) whose declaration (just above that in your code) shows 0 formal generics.